# Dithered image larger than original (using the Rust image crate)

Tags: image, rust

I'm learning Rust and wanted to try my hand at error diffusion dithering. I've got it working, but the dithered file ends up bigger than the original, which is the opposite of what's supposed to happen. The original JPEG image is 605 KB big, but the dithered image has a whopping 2.57 MB. My knowledge of the image crate is very limited and I found all the various structs for representing images confusing, so I must be missing something regarding the API.

Here's the code for dithering the image (included are only parts which I deemed relevant):

```rust
impl DiffusionKernel<'_> {
    pub const FLOYD_STEINBERG: DiffusionKernel<'_> = // Constructor

    fn distribute_error(
        &self,
        error: &(i16, i16, i16),
        image: &mut DynamicImage,
        width: u32,
        height: u32,
        x: u32,
        y: u32,
    ) {
        for target in self.targets /* "targets" are the pixels where to distribute the error */ {
            // Checks if the target x and y are in the bounds of the image
            // Also returns the x and y coordinates of the pixel, because the "target" struct only describes the offset of the target pixel from the pixel being currently processed
            let (is_valid_target, target_x, target_y) =
                DiffusionKernel::is_valid_target(target, width, height, x, y);

            if is_valid_target == false {
                continue;
            }

            let target_pix = image.get_pixel(target_x, target_y);

            // Distribute the error to the target_pix

            let new_pix = Rgba::from([new_r, new_g, new_b, 255]);

            image.put_pixel(target_x, target_y, new_pix);
        }
    }

    pub fn diffuse(&self, bit_depth: u8, image: &mut DynamicImage) {
        let width = image.width();
        let height = image.height();

        for x in 0..width {
            for y in 0..height {
                let pix = image.get_pixel(x, y);
                let pix_quantized = ColorUtil::reduce_color_bit_depth(pix, bit_depth); // Quantizes the color
                let error = (
                    pix.0[0] as i16 - pix_quantized.0[0] as i16,
                    pix.0[1] as i16 - pix_quantized.0[1] as i16,
                    pix.0[2] as i16 - pix_quantized.0[2] as i16,
                );

                image.put_pixel(x, y, pix_quantized);
                self.distribute_error(&error, image, width, height, x, y);
            }
        }

        // Distributing the error ends up creating colors like 7, 7, 7, or 12, 12, 12 instead of 0, 0, 0 for black,
        // so here I'm just ensuring that the colors are correctly quantized.
        // I think the algorithm shouldn't behave like this, I'll try to fix it later.
        for x in 0..width {
            for y in 0..height {
                let pix = image.get_pixel(x, y);
                let pix_quantized = ColorUtil::reduce_color_bit_depth(pix, bit_depth);
                image.put_pixel(x, y, pix_quantized);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for loading and saving the image:

```rust
let format = "jpg";
let path = String::from("C:\\...\\Cat.".to_owned() + format);

let trimmed_path = path.trim(); // This needs to be here if I'm getting the path from the console

let bfr = Reader::open(trimmed_path)
    .unwrap()
    .with_guessed_format()
    .unwrap();
let mut dynamic = bfr.decode().unwrap();
// dynamic = dynamic.grayscale();
error_diffusion::DiffusionKernel::FLOYD_STEINBERG.diffuse(1, &mut dynamic);

dynamic
    .save(trimmed_path.to_owned() + "_dithered." + format)
    .expect("There was an error saving the image.");
```

Comment: Why do you expect dithering to shrink the file size if you don't switch encoding as well. Afaik you'd have to use a different format i.e 8 bits color depth instead of 24 or something to reduce the size.

Comment: From the point of view of the JPEG encoder, dithering is seen as adding noise, which will tend to _increase_ the file size all things being equal. But in your case, all things are _not_ equal since you don't use the same JPEG quantization as the original anyway, so comparing file sizes is pointless.

Comment: @cafce25 How can I do that? I found some encoders and the ColorType enum, but I don't know how to use them. The JpegEncoder has an encode method, which I assume is the one you're talking about, but the u8 buffer confuses me. How can I convert the image pixels to a u8 slice?

Comment: The `image` crate only offers basic reading and writing of images. Specifying a specific encoding other than the [`ImageFormat`](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.5/image/enum.ImageFormat.html#)s doesn't seem to be part of it.

Comment: What about the [ColorType](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/enum.ColorType.html) enum and the [JpegEncoder](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/codecs/jpeg/struct.JpegEncoder.html) struct which I mentioned? What other way could I change the color depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got back to trying to figure this out, and it looks like you just need to use an image encoder like the [PngEncoder](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.5/image/codecs/png/struct.PngEncoder.html) and a file to write to in order to lower the bit depth of an image. The encoder takes bytes, not pixels, but thankfully, images have a `as_bytes` method which returns what you need.

Here's the code:

```rust
let img = image::open(path).expect("Failed to open image.");
let (width, height) = img.dimensions();
let writer = File::create(path.to_owned() + "_out.png").unwrap();
// This is the best encoder configuration for black/white images, which is my output
// Grayscale with multiple colors -> black/white using dithering
let encoder = PngEncoder::new_with_quality(writer, CompressionType::Best, FilterType::NoFilter);

encoder
  .write_image(img.as_bytes(), width, height, ColorType::L8)
  .expect("Failed to write image.");
```